# Jwt configuration file not published after installation

Tags: php, laravel, jwt, laravel-5.4

I added jwt to my Laravel application using the explanation on the official repository [jwt-auth installation wiki](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/wiki/Installation). The installation was successful (that is after running a composer update). At that stage I was left with adding jwt to the services and aliases array and running the publish command to publish the configuration file.

Using

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\JWTAuthServiceProvider"
```

The command above runs and displays `Publishing complete` However this is not the expected behavior I expect it to show the name of the configuration file jwt.php generated. That is not case and as expected running the next command

```
php artisan jwt:generate
```

returns and error

```
[Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException]  
  There are no commands defined in the "jwt" namespace.
```

And I guess that is because the jwt.php config file is absent, what am I missing here? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. The following worked for me:

```
php artisan config:clear

php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\JWTAuthServiceProvider::class"

php artisan config:cache

php artisan vendor:publish
```

Answer (score 2):

To install the `tymon/jwt-auth` package in laravel, one should follow the following steps:

Composer.json require should be like this:

```
"require": {
       "php": ">=5.5.9",
       "laravel/framework": "5.1.*",
       "tymon/jwt-auth": "0.5.*"
   },
```

Then in config/app.php put the following in the providers array:

```
Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\JWTAuthServiceProvider::class
```

Then in the aliases array in the config/app.php add the following

```
'JWTAuth'   => Tymon\JWTAuthFacades\JWTAuth::class,
'JWTFactory' => Tymon\JWTAuthFacades\JWTFactory::class
```

Then type the following command:

```
php artisan vendor:publish
```

Note: Various tutorials will suggest you do the following :

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Tymon\JWTAuthProviders\JWTAuthServiceProvider"
```

However, before that, try the above command without --provider and it will work.

Then type:

```
php artisan jwt:generate
```

After this step, you can verify the generated key in `app/config/jwt.php` as mentioned below:

```
'secret' => env('JWT_SECRET', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'),
```

Now, you are good to go...

Answer (score 1):

I am posting this answer days after I solved the problem, since no answers are coming up.
After some research I found that the main reason a config file may not be published despite correct installation is the due to confusion in the `config:cache` when new configs are added. However I solved the problem by running

```
php artisan config:clear
```

Then run the publish command again and boom!! it worked. This method will work not only for JWT but for other configurations that fail to publish but it is good to note that the problem can be caused by other things as well.

Comment: @geoidesic can you give more details about how your own behaved? This might hep us find a solution.

Comment: @ F.E Noel Nfebe – I think in my case it is because JWT was not included in composer.json. I wasn't able to install JWT however because of dependency hell.

Comment: @geoidesic please do well do add an answer and a description if you finally solved the problem so more and more people can get help.

Comment: @ F.E Noel Nfebe I haven't solved the problem. I don't think it is solvable because there are unresolvable dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following snippet to the bootstrap/app.php file under the providers section as follows:

```
// Uncomment this line
$app->register(App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class);

// Add this line
$app->register(Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\LumenServiceProvider::class);
```

Then uncomment the auth middleware in the same file:

```
$app->routeMiddleware([
    'auth' => App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

For Lumen 5.5.*

```
$ composer require tymon/jwt-auth:"^1.0.0"
```

Add blow code into app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php register method:

```
$this->app->register(\Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\LumenServiceProvider::class);
```

Answer (score 0):

for laravel 5.5 and later install jwt version 1.0.0-rc.1 works well, you DON'T need register jwt class in service providers just require it with composer:

```
composer require tymon/jwt-auth:1.0.0-rc.1
```

after that you can publish.

Answer (score 0):

If your laravel version is 5.8 then refer [this](https://medium.com/@manuelmauriciozamarrn/implementing-jwt-on-laravel-5-8-edc39f545886) document.

For 5.8 you have to first generate secret key.

`$php artisan jwt:secret`

then add JWTAuth provider.

`$php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\LaravelServiceProvider"`